# How do I create multiple sessions in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an issue were I need insert function, admin_list_students set for only admin to login and access these function or webpages. Then I need it so the user only access the user_list_students. Currently when the user logs in they can also access the admin area. I tried setting up 2 different login pages but again when user logs in they can access admin pages.

student.php controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Student extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login/student_model');

        }   

    //Shows the dashboard
    public function index()
    {
         if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        {

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('student');
        $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login/header');
            $this->load->view('login/content'); 
            $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }
    }
    //Insert the Student 
    public function  insert_student()
    {
        $interest=implode(',',$this->input->post('interest'));
        $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
            'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
            'year'=>$this->input->post('year'),
            'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
            'interest'=>$interest,
            'status'=>1);
        //print_r($data);

        $result=$this->student_model->insert_student($data);
        if($result==true)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Student Records Added Successfully");
            redirect('student');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->seesion->set_flashdata('msg1',"Student Records Added Failed");
            redirect('student');


        }
    }
    //List of students 
        public function admin_list_students()
    {
         if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        {

            $data['student']=$this->student_model->get_student();
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('admin_list_of_students',$data);
             $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('login/header');
            $this->load->view('login/content'); 
             $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }
    }
    //List of students 
        public function user_list_students()
    {
         if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        {

            $data['student']=$this->student_model->get_student();
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('user_list_of_students',$data);
             $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('login/header');
            $this->load->view('login/content'); 
             $this->load->view('login/footer');
        }
    }


    public function delete_student()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $data=array('status'=>0);
        $result=$this->student_model->delete_student($id,$data);
        if($result==true)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Deleted Successfully");
            redirect('student/list_students');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Student Records Deletion Failed");
            redirect('student/list_students');


        }

    }
    public function edit_student()
    {
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['student']=$this->student_model->edit_student($id);
        $this->load->view('header',$data);
        $this->load->view('edit_student');
    }
    public function  update_student()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $interest=implode(',',$this->input->post('interest'));
        $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
            'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
            'year'=>$this->input->post('year'),
            'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
            'interest'=>$interest,
            'status'=>1);

        $result=$this->student_model->update_student($data,$id);
        if($result==true)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Student Records Updated Successfully");
            redirect('student/list_students');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"No changes Made in Student Records");
            redirect('student/list_students');


        }
    }

}
?>
```

login.php controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    /**
    * Check if the user is logged in, if he's not, 
    * send him to the login page
    * @return void
    */  
    function index()
    {

        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
        {
            redirect('student');
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login/header');
            $this->load->view('login/content'); 
        }
    }

    /**
    * encript the password 
    * @return mixed
    */  
    function __encrip_password($password) {
        return md5($password);

    }   

    /**
    * check the username and the password with the database
    * @return void
    */

    function validate()
    {   
        $this->load->model('login/login_model');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->__encrip_password($this->input->post('password'));
        $is_valid = $this->login_model->validate($username, $password);

        if($is_valid)/*If valid username and password set */
        {
            $get_id = $this->login_model->get_id($username, $password);

            foreach($get_id as $val)
                { 
                     $mobileno = $val->mobileno;
                     $fname = $val->firstname;
                     $lname = $val->lastname;
                     $state = $val->state;
                     $email=$val->email;
                     $city = $val->city;
                     $username=$val->username;
                     $adminid=$val->admin_id;

            }
           $data = array(
                'mobileno'=>$mobileno,
                'firstname'=>$fname,
                'lastname'=>$lname,
                'email'=>$email,
                'state'=>$state,
                'city'=>$city,
                'admin_id' => $adminid,
                'username' => $username,
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
        //  print_r($data);
            $this->session->set_userdata($data); /*Here you can set the values in session */
            redirect('student');
        }
        else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username or Password Incorrect');
            redirect('login');
        }

    }

    /**
        * Destroy the session, and logout the user.
        * @return void
    */      
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }

}
```

login.php model

```
<?php

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    /**
    * Validate the login's data with the database
    * @param string $user_name
    * @param string $password
    * @return void
    */

    /*Check Login*/
    function validate($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get('membership');
        if($query->num_rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }       
    }

    /*Get Session values */

    function get_id($username, $password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('membership');
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an additional value, say **is_admin** in validate()->$data array. Based on this paramenter you give acces to certan admin areas of the website, like this:
In **student.php** controller,

```
public function admin_list_students()
    {
         if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') and $this->session->userdata('is_admin'))
        { ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to set the type of user in database table if you strore different type of user in one table and when logging in the user you have to save the type of user withi his unique id in session
and you have to check this type in when giving access.

Answer (score 0):

you set your session 'is_logged_in' for both user and admin so user can view admin pages.

add usertype as a table field,when insert add as 'admin' or 'user' as it is.

when you set session set usertype `$this->session->set_userdata('usertype')`
and check as 
`$this->session->userdata('usertype') == 'admin'` 
or 
`$this->session->userdata('usertype') == 'user'`